# Identifying a mixture model given the mixing and the outcome distribution

Tags: references, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, mixture-distribution, identifiability

Consider a mixture model involving an observed random variable $Y$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}$ with cdf $F$, a mixing random variable $\alpha$ taking values in a set $\mathcal{A}$ with cdf $G$ and a set of factors, i.e. a collection of cdfs $(F(y|\alpha))_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}$.

Suppose I know $F$ and $G$ and that the two are related as above. How can I charachterise the set of plausible factors? In other words how can I charachterise
$$\mathcal{F}(F,G)=\left\{(F(y|\alpha))_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}\ |\ F(y)=\int F(y|\alpha)dG(\alpha)\right\}$$
Can I say something on the conditional moments of the factors, for instance, given $a\in\mathcal{A}$ what can I say about
$$\mathcal{E}(F,G,a)=\{ E[Y|\alpha=a]\ |\  (F(y|a),(\tilde{F}(y|\alpha))_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}\setminus a})\in \mathcal{F}(F,G)\ for\ some\  (\tilde{F}(y|\alpha))_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}\setminus a} \}$$

I would be happy about result which make further assumptions too (e.g. finite factors,parametric assumptions on the distributions etc).

Thanks for any help or reference.